# install RQuantLib on Microsoft Windows

Tags: c++, r, cygwin, quantlib

I need to install the R package **RQuantLib** on a Microsoft Windows machine. There is no binary for this package so I downloaded the tar source.

I opened it and it contains the QuantLib C++ libraries. So I need to compile the package.

I don't want to install Visual Studio and I use eclipse IDE. Can I use the compiler cygwin to compile the C code of the RQuantLib package? Will the resulting compiled code be usable by R on my windows machine?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

begin shameless plug

I wrote about [how to build RQuantLib on Windows](http://blog.fosstrading.com/2010/12/build-rquantlib-on-32-bit-windows.html) on my blog.  I didn't try it with Cygwin, but you can do it with MinGW.

end shameless plug

Comment: thanks Josh. You are everywhere in R :) I should read more often your blog!

Comment: Ulrish: OK I have installed the MinGW with MSYS now. But when using the MSYS shell with the command set PATH=c:/MinGW/bin;%PATH%, I get the error: "sh: fg: %PATH%: no such job"

Comment: @Fred: whoops, I confused Windows and *nix commands there.  That's what I get for writing the instructions from memory.  Try `set PATH=c:/MinGW/bin:$PATH`.